# How to update the data after calling API?

Tags: reactjs, dispatch

This MainUserManagement.js consists of three components, including the sidebar, List and search. When loading the App.js, the useEffect in the mainUserManagement.js will automatically call the API to get a list of employees and display it in the List. So, the value of the `users` in line 3 will be the list of employees. The value of the `post` in line 6 at this stage equals null.

When performing the search function, it will call another API. I will get a new list of employees and the value of the `post` in line 6 will be the new list. I want to update the value inside the List, but `<List users={users || post} />` doesn't work. It only displays the `users`. What should I do?

```
const MainUserManagement = () => {
  const [userState, userDispatch] = useUser();
  const { users } = userState;

  const [postState] = usePost();
  const { post } = postState;

  const getAllUSersInfoHandler = async () => {
    await listEmployee(userDispatch);
    setLoadingUser(userDispatch, false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllUSersInfoHandler();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div class="page">
      <div className="rows">
        <PostState>
          <UserState>
            <div className="left-column"><SideBar /></div>
            <div className="mid-column"><List users={users || post} /></div>
            <div className="right-column"><Search users={users} /></div>
          </UserState>
        </PostState>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainUserManagement;
```

Comment: Can we see your search function ? Check this demo for a simple search (+ debounce) if it can help you : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qyhabz?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: I believe on initial render post should not have any data (undefined). So in that case you can do something `<List users={post || user} />` so that when post data exist it will get the precedence. Otherwise you can update the data either from user or post on condition before the render statement or in useEffect (with dependency of users and post state)

Comment: I have tried the first method, but it will make the value inside the List becomes empty. For the second method, I am trying to understand what that means. In the useEffect, it will do a series of actions and get the value of `user`. Then, it will assign it to the List. At this stage, the `post` is null. So, I can add a condition in the useEffect. if post=== null, then loads the user to users. After the search, the post equals a new list. At this time, useEffect check post !== null, load post to users? @user1672994

Comment: Yes, something like that.